# How to: Zend .htaccess Lighttpd conversion

Tags: .htaccess, lighttpd, rewrite, zend-framework

We are using Zend Framework, we switched from apache to lighttpd, main htaccess file for zend is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php
```

What is the lighttpd equivalent of this ? I found one line here,

```
url.rewrite-once = (".*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$" => "$0", "" => "/index.php")
```

but it doesn't first two lines of the original (

> if file and dir exists then don't

lines)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a open feature request but it's over 2 years old. 
[Request: mod_rewrite check if file exists (like mod_rewrite in apache)](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/985)

There is also a user commited patch [available](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/985#note-28)